# Check if point is inside of shape drawn by a complex Path2D

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, html5-canvas, path-2d

I want to check if a given point is inside of the space drawn inside of a irregular path - inside of the brain (the path is below).

I don't seem to be able to use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath(path, x, y)` because it only returns true if the point is literally inside the path (the white outline).

I also don't think I can use the odd polygon rule, given that it is possible for a point not to be in the edge and its line still hit the shape wall an even number of times...

[image: Shape]

Comment: Can you provide the code that draws the actual path in question?

Comment: Well... It's not drawn by code at all... The path (the brain image) is an SVG image I got from the internet. So I have the path, but not the code used to draw it. I'm thinking I could maybe fill the SVG on Photoshop and get its path then... Maybe it'd work. Gonna try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're working with a SVG, here's a workaround which doesn't involve any abstract calculations.

### (1)

Make the inside of your shape, thus the area you want to detect a color completely different from the rest of the shape or any other visuals. In your case for example it would be nothing (or black) to red.

[image]

This is controlled by the svg's `fill` attribute, which takes a hex `#ff0000` or a rgb value `rgb(255,0,0)`. Well for reasons that will be important later we make it a `rgba(255,0,0,1)` value though it ignores the alpha value.

As we don't want the fill to be visible, we also need to set the `fill-opacity` value to `0.005`. This is the lowest value possible and equals the CanvasRenderingContext2D value of 1 in a range from 0-255.

### (2)

Now we need to turn the svg into an Image object that can be drawn onto a canvas. This can be done using the following lines:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let img = new Image();
img.onload = function(e) {
    ctx.drawImage(e.currentTarget, canvas.width / 2 - 50, canvas.height / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
}
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);
```

`svg` is just a string representation of your svg's data.

### (3)

The final step involves getting the pixel color at a specific position on the canvas. For this we utilize the `.getImageData(x, y, width, height)` method, which returns an object consisting of a `Uint8ClampedArray` which holds four values per pixel. If we set both `width` and `height` to 1 we get exactly the four color components for a single pixel - `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha`.

Now we simply compare the color with the red we've used in step (1) and if it's equal, we know it's inside the shape.

Here's a working example (hover your mouse over the image):

```js
let hitColor = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
let svg = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 511.989 511.989" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.989 511.989;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:${hitColor};fill-opacity:0.005" d="M489.333,255.088l-21.344-17.625l8-34.671l4-18.812l-30.656-42.141l6.656-22.53l-8-38.483
    l-30.655-30.077h-39.999c0,0-22.655,12.312-16,0c6.672-12.328-33.326-36.577-33.326-36.577h-17.328l-40.663,15.483l-9.602,7.828
    l-31.062-23.702h-30.672l-23.999,0.391l-20.929,23.312L150.41,50.75h-22.383l-23.998,10.654L66.694,73.295l-6.664,29.358
    l-5.336,42.577l-19.999,22.891v26.516l12.397,37.623l-12.397,16.547l-18.664,22.672v41.326l18.664,29.984v36.67l23.999,55.999
    c0,0,35.999,18.672,41.335,21.327c5.328,2.672,14.664,0,14.664,0l29.327,32l27.999,9.328h21.336l42.663-18.656l24.397-18.672
    l10.664,24l42.257,13.328h21.344l31.998-6.656l21.719-38.671l11.609,3.999l38.67-7.999l28-28.327l10.656-46.327v-31.343
    l17.718-20.156l10.281-35.171L489.333,255.088z"/>
<path style="fill:#ffffff;" d="M511.973,294.009c0-24.546-12.891-46.093-32.28-58.218c7.984-11.203,12.672-24.905,12.672-39.701
    c0-22.203-10.562-41.938-26.938-54.453c2.625-7.655,4.078-15.858,4.078-24.42c0-41.281-33.484-74.749-74.764-74.749
    c-8.344,0-16.375,1.375-23.875,3.906C363.21,19.594,338.554,0,309.321,0c-22.266,0-41.858,11.359-53.327,28.608
    C244.525,11.359,224.925,0,202.667,0c-29.233,0-53.889,19.594-61.537,46.374c-7.5-2.531-15.531-3.906-23.89-3.906
    c-41.288,0-74.757,33.468-74.757,74.749c0,8.562,1.445,16.765,4.086,24.42c-16.382,12.516-26.952,32.25-26.952,54.453
    c0,14.796,4.695,28.498,12.672,39.701c-19.383,12.125-32.273,33.672-32.273,58.218c0,21.327,9.727,40.374,24.984,52.952
    c-2.375,8.375-3.656,17.202-3.656,26.343c0,52.53,42.194,95.185,94.537,95.966c13.405,25.406,40.069,42.719,70.787,42.719
    c29.632,0,55.506-16.125,69.326-40.062c13.82,23.938,39.687,40.062,69.327,40.062c30.718,0,57.389-17.312,70.795-42.719
    c52.342-0.781,94.529-43.436,94.529-95.966c0-9.141-1.281-17.968-3.656-26.343C502.238,334.383,511.973,315.336,511.973,294.009z
     M186.668,490.644c-32.351,0-58.663-26.312-58.663-58.654c0-16.406,7.195-31.688,18.078-42.344c2.008-1.938,3.25-4.641,3.25-7.656
    c0-5.891-4.773-10.655-10.664-10.655c-2.906,0-5.547,1.156-7.469,3.047c-15.569,14.593-24.53,34.577-24.53,57.608
    c0,5.265,0.516,10.421,1.492,15.405c-16.469-2-31.702-9.391-43.616-21.312c-14.102-14.094-21.867-32.844-21.867-52.78
    c0-19.952,7.766-38.702,21.867-52.796c14.102-14.109,32.851-21.875,52.796-21.875c6.351,0,12.585,0.781,18.585,2.312
    c0.883,0.234,1.797,0.375,2.742,0.375c5.891,0,10.664-4.78,10.664-10.671c0-5.203-3.727-9.531-8.656-10.469
    c-7.477-1.875-15.289-2.875-23.335-2.875c-35.805,0-67.03,19.608-83.529,48.655c-7.734-8.422-12.469-19.641-12.469-31.952
    c0-16.406,8.32-31.405,22.265-40.14l9.789-6.125c2.898-1.906,4.812-5.188,4.812-8.922c0-2.266-0.719-4.391-1.938-6.109l-6.609-9.297
    c-5.695-7.999-8.711-17.452-8.711-27.326c0-13.922,6.07-26.453,15.695-35.094c13.578,18.766,35.655,30.984,60.593,30.984
    c5.89,0,10.765-4.781,10.765-10.672s-4.844-10.656-10.733-10.656c-29.453,0-53.452-23.969-53.452-53.436
    c0-29.453,23.968-53.422,53.421-53.422c7.679,0,14.976,1.641,21.585,4.562c2.242,33.312,29.968,59.624,63.842,59.624
    c5.891,0,10.664-4.766,10.664-10.671c0-5.891-4.773-10.657-10.664-10.657c-23.522,0-42.663-19.14-42.663-42.671
    c0-23.515,19.133-42.655,42.663-42.655c23.523,0,42.663,19.141,42.663,42.655v106.67h-0.016
    c-0.156,5.734-4.867,10.359-10.655,10.359c-5.891,0-10.664,4.781-10.664,10.672s4.773,10.671,10.664,10.671
    c3.741,0,7.335-0.656,10.671-1.828v87.451c0,17.64-14.358,31.983-31.999,31.983c-5.891,0-10.664,4.781-10.664,10.672
    s4.773,10.672,10.664,10.672c12.008,0,23.086-3.969,31.999-10.672v101.357C245.33,464.332,219.011,490.644,186.668,490.644z
     M478.177,325.961c-16.5-29.047-47.718-48.655-83.529-48.655c-8.047,0-15.859,1-23.344,2.875c-4.922,0.938-8.656,5.266-8.656,10.469
    c0,5.891,4.781,10.671,10.672,10.671c0.953,0,1.859-0.141,2.734-0.375c6-1.531,12.25-2.312,18.594-2.312
    c19.938,0,38.687,7.766,52.795,21.875c14.109,14.094,21.859,32.844,21.859,52.796c0,19.937-7.75,38.687-21.859,52.78
    c-11.922,11.921-27.14,19.312-43.607,21.312c0.969-4.984,1.484-10.141,1.484-15.405c0-23.031-8.953-43.016-24.531-57.608
    c-1.922-1.891-4.562-3.047-7.469-3.047c-5.891,0-10.672,4.765-10.672,10.655c0,3.016,1.25,5.719,3.25,7.656
    c10.891,10.656,18.094,25.938,18.094,42.344c0,32.342-26.312,58.654-58.67,58.654c-32.344,0-58.663-26.312-58.663-58.654V330.633
    c8.914,6.703,19.991,10.672,31.991,10.672c5.906,0,10.672-4.781,10.672-10.672s-4.766-10.672-10.672-10.672
    c-17.625,0-31.991-14.344-31.991-31.983v-87.451c3.336,1.172,6.93,1.828,10.663,1.828c5.891,0,10.672-4.78,10.672-10.671
    c0-5.891-4.781-10.672-10.672-10.672c-5.78,0-10.491-4.625-10.647-10.359h-0.016V63.982c0-23.515,19.147-42.655,42.663-42.655
    s42.671,19.141,42.671,42.655c0,23.531-19.155,42.671-42.671,42.671c-5.891,0-10.672,4.767-10.672,10.657
    c0,5.905,4.781,10.671,10.672,10.671c33.874,0,61.607-26.312,63.842-59.624c6.609-2.922,13.906-4.562,21.578-4.562
    c29.468,0,53.436,23.969,53.436,53.422c0,29.467-23.999,53.436-53.467,53.436c-5.891,0-10.719,4.766-10.719,10.656
    c0,5.89,4.875,10.672,10.75,10.672c24.937,0,47.029-12.219,60.592-30.984c9.625,8.641,15.703,21.172,15.703,35.094
    c0,9.874-3.016,19.327-8.719,27.326l-6.609,9.297c-1.219,1.719-1.938,3.844-1.938,6.109c0,3.734,1.922,7.016,4.812,8.922
    l9.797,6.125c13.938,8.734,22.266,23.733,22.266,40.14C490.645,306.32,485.911,317.539,478.177,325.961z"/>
</svg>
`;
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
let img = new Image();
img.onload = function(e) {
  ctx.drawImage(e.target, canvas.width / 2 - 50, canvas.height / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    let data = ctx.getImageData(e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top, 1, 1).data;
    let hit = hitColor == `rgba(${data[0]},${data[1]},${data[2]},${data[3]})`;
    document.getElementById('message').innerText = `inside path: ${hit}`;
  });
}
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background:black;"></canvas><br>
<span id="message">inside path:</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it as soon as possible but I can see it'll definitively work, besides this seems like the best approach.